# "Before long" and "after long"

Tags: grammaticality

This question is inspired by a chat conversation during which I was corrected on the use of *after long*. Certainly,

> He will be back **before** long

is correct. However, is

> He will be back **after** long

grammatical? If not, why does changing *before* to *after* make it wrong?

Comment: [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/long?q=before+long#long__30) says that *long* is a mass noun, not an adverb. However the answer is almost certainly one of idiom.

Comment: "after long" is not grammatical. "before long" means "before a long time has passed" somewhat of a litotes.

Comment: *Long* does not work as an adverb here; the entire phrase "before long" works as an adverb. And the entire phrase is an idiom. You can't replace *before* with *after* for much the same reason you can't replace *cats* with *cows* in "it's raining cats and dogs".

Comment: _Long_ is short for _a long time_ in this sense; and it occurs in other environments as well. It's a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) in _It didn't take long._ vs _*It took long._ _Before long_ is an idiom; _after long_ isn't -- _after a long time_ is OK, but it's not common enough to license the deletion and semantic freezing.

Comment: You could expand it some, and say, for example, "He will be back after a long delay." I think "before long" is simply an established [idiom](http://books.google.com/books?id=ytJNRDL0zDgC&pg=PA231&dq=%22before+long%22+idiom&hl=en&sa=X&ei=g16lUIWZJdDU0gGcjoCYAw#v=onepage&q=%22before%20long%22%20idiom&f=false) for "before much time elapses."

Comment: 'After _so_ long' **is** acceptable: _Meeting old friends after so long can be awkward_. 'Before so long' seems to ring a bell with me, but there are only a few Google hits - including '... That you'll be back before so long. ...' from a Hank Marvin song. 'Before too long' is the more usual variant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just a matter of idiomatic usage. [This NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=before%20long&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) suggests that *before long* didn't really become established until early/mid C19, and many of the (relatively few) earlier instances involve extended forms such as ["before long time be spent"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7HbLmrwQOesC&pg=PA100&dq=%22before%20long%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TmKlUO_-H4W40QXy9YFo&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22before%20long%22&f=false).

To my mind, all that's happened is that *before long* has become an established shortened form of *before **a** long **time** [passes/has passed/had passed]*.

As it happens, the corresponding shortening didn't occur with ***after*** long. There's no special reason why it should have, and thus no reason to say this fundamentally differentiates *before* and *after*.

---

As John comments, *long* itself is often a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), which is why we can say *"It didn't take long"*, but not *"*It took long"*. Possibly (I'm guessing wildly here) this encouraged the uptake of *before long* (because *"before"* there effectively negates the long passage of time), whereas with *after long* you'd be *affirming* that passage of time.

Comment: COCA has 286 cites for "after long", but only two of them are relevant at all (the rest is of the form "after long [noun]"). 1. 1994, *The Shawshank Redemption:* "First you hate' em, then you get used to' em. After long enough, you get so you depend on' em." 2. 1995, SPOKEN: "LIMBAUGH: I'll tell you what. Somebody points their finger that close to me, that many times does not have that finger after long, I'll tell you." The first one has that appendix, *enough*, that ruins it for us, and the second one is careless speech, possibly even a one-off error. At any rate, not much to work with.

Comment: @Will Hunting: [I hope not after long, I shall be able to write something more satisfactory.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+hope+not+after+long%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) That's from 1841, which may or may not be relevant to the fact that it sounds "archaic" to me. Curiously, I note several apparently non-native speakers writing ["**not** after long the..."](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22not+after+long+the%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), so maybe they've latched on to the "negative polarity" bit, but didn't know about the "established idiom" side of things.